# Remove all elements in one list and add to another list - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

So I'm trying to remove all cards from a player's 'Rack' (an ArrayList) and put it in the discard pile (Stack), one by one. So far I have the following code which I've come to realize will stop once it hits 5. (Note: each players rack has 10 cards).

```
        int rackSize = player.getPlayerRack().getRack().size(); // rackSize = 10
        for (int i = 0; i < rackSize; i++) {
            getDeck().getDiscardPile().add(player.getPlayerRack().getRack().remove(i));
        }
```

My question is how do I remove all items in the players 'Rack' so the rackSize = 0, and add all of them to the discard pile?

Terribly sorry if this is confusing. You can generalize this by saying there are 10 integers in an `ArrayList<Integer> hand`, so: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. How would you remove all items from this list and add them to a `Stack<Integer> discardPile`?

Comment: What do you mean by "will stop at 5"? Does it fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception?

Comment: Why would it stop at 5?

Comment: Why one by one? Why not just call `addAll()` and then `clear()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is as you're removing the elements from `Rack`, you're still incrementing with `i++`, meaning that the new value at the old index `i` is still left behind. What you'll want to do is change your code to this:

```
int rackSize = player.getPlayerRack().getRack().size(); // rackSize = 10
for (int i = 0; i < rackSize; i++) {
    getDeck().getDiscardPile().add(player.getPlayerRack().getRack().remove(0));
}
```

This way, you're always reaching into the first new element in the `Rack` until it's empty, assuming `Rack` is not repopulated while this code is executing.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks! I couldn't for the life of me think of how to do that for some reason.

Comment: @superp0s Haha, thanks! It's a common mistake. BTW, I like your style of defensive programming, initializing `rackSize` outside of the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks! I'm partially doing it because my professor requires our lines to be no more than 80 columns long, and I guess that's a good habit to get into, so this was kind of my option. It also makes it easier to read, so I should probably start using it more where it may make logical sense for the person reading my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0 instead of `i` to access the ArrayList.

When you remove an element, it is no longer in the ArrayList so you have to keep this is mind - further references through the array index should be decremented 1 in each iteration. As a result you probably want to access the first item every time.